Jetwoobuilder plugin prevent using the hook woocommerce_thankyou
I'm using Jetwoobuilder to design the woocommerce pages
But I need to get the order id as soon the order is placed
So I've used this
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'get_order_id');
   
Function get_order_id($order_id){

//rest code

}

But the code doesn't work until I disable Jetwoobuilder plugin
How to force using the woocommerce_thankyou hook while using Jetwoobuilder plugin please ?
